# How to build a query and search on Google for text insights of first few results

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, google-search-api

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) in which I have to get a string as query from the user and then build a query and search on Google, after I need to grab the first 5 records and perform text insights from those results, the response could be a text insight, a code or a patch file.

I'm little bit confused about the text insights and grab the user's relevant information like code snippets or pach file, how can I get these things?

Here's how I'm performing the query:

```
@app.route('/<string:query>', methods=['GET'])
def search_query(query):
    results = []
    for j in search(query, tld='com', num=5, start=0, stop=5,
                    pause=2.0):
        print(j)
        results.append(j)
        # here I need to return user's reletive info from first 5 results


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: you can do this using beautifulSoup, if you wish to use that i can help you with the code.

Comment: help me with code, please!

Comment: Did you try the answer?

Answer (score 0):

To scrape your google search you need to first create a underlying search using `requests` python library then scrape the links using `BeautifulSoup` and then just pick first 5 from them so that in future if you decide to get more than 5 link, you won't have to change much code.

Also, you need to install these libraries:

**`BeautifulSoup`**

**`requests`**

**`html5lib`**      -  **`pip install html5lib`**            <--- Html Tree parser

ps - I'm sure you know all this but this is for lesser

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def search_query(query):

    url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='
    url_data = url + query
    raw = get(url_data)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(raw.content, 'html5lib')
    links = soup.find_all('a')
    allinks = []
    for link in links:
        a = link['href']
        if a.startswith('/url?'):         #<---- links starting from /url are the ones we want
            a = a.lstrip('/url?q=')       #<----using lstrip i take that part out
            a = a.split('&sa=')[0]        #<-----options, shortens the link without tampering with it
            allinks.append(a)
    print(allinks[:5])         #<----testing
    return allinks[:5]         #<-----Return it
```